# Symfony 2 App debug mode error

Tags: debugging, symfony

I'm trying to implement a twig custom error pages in a Symfony website (just following the cookbook), but when i turn off debug mode (throught app kernel in app.php) the whole application get error 500 from server.

When debug mode is true, the application works fine.

Anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your server's error logs and also `app/logs/prod.log` you will find the error causing the 500 error there. Sometimes clearing the cache `rm -rf app/cache/prod` also helps.

Comment: I've looked the log files (apache and symfony) and the cause was, i don't know why yet, with debug mode false, my app does not generate doctrine/orm/proxies cache files.

Comment: seems like a permissions issue maybe?